# HTTP POST fill Form - objective C

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, http-post

I know if you have a web view you can click a button through code like this

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('GL')[0].click()"];
```

But if you fill out a form with a POST to a website, not with a UIWebView, then I how can you submit the form with a POST, or can you not do this? Or is there another way to submit the form?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

from your question it seems that you want to click the submit button to submit the form .
you can do this using something like this:
    function{
    document.            getElementById("submit").  click();
     }
This will click the submit button like manually clicking the submit button regardless of the get or post method . Hope this helps.